# Fully dark theme/mode?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

Since the whole network is getting a more consistent theming all across its sites, why not adding a dark theme (/dark mode to the theme), as well?

It's not just about the ongoing (mobile) "AMOLEDification" trend, but also about plain eye comfort; it's just more comfortable, specially at night/under low light, so maybe a full dark mode should also be considered, while at it.

Comment: They screwed up the [SU] redesign. I don't trust them to get a dark mode right

Comment: People have been asking for this for ages - and there's a ton of userscripts and extensions for it to happen. That said, I've never heard TPTB express any interest in making a dark theeme

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/386150 is a recent MSO discussion on this.

Comment: Reason I posted this is because I searched for "dark theme" and "dark mode" and found nothing, here.

Comment: Is there any update to this? Seems we're being left in the light...

Comment: Hopefully we get it some day…